# Is it possibleto bar graph rainfall data in parallel with with a temporal animation

Tags: qgis, chart, temporal-controller

I have an animation of red squirrel sightings in Clocaenog Forest over time (one year).  I would like to display a bar graph of rainfall and temperature for each day as the animation displays.  I know there are graphing facilities in QGIS, can they be displayed in a temporal animation?

Comment: I haven't used it, so I don't know if it will suit your purposes, but you can look into QGIS' temporal controller.  There are other GIS tools such as GeoDA, that display box plots, scatter plots, and other graphs as an animation over time.

Comment: The Temporal Controller is a very useful tool but has one failing, there is no "decoration" for a Legend.  It is possible to overlay a graphic but this wont update as the legend in print view does.